# foreign key is null Springboot jpa

Tags: java, spring-boot, foreign-keys, h2

customer

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor

@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    private Long customerId;

    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "house_no")
    private String houseNo;

    
    @Column(name = "active")
    private boolean active = true;

    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "customer_type")
    private String customerType;

    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "pack")
    private String pack;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "customer",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Stb stb;

    @JsonIgnore
     @OneToOne(mappedBy = "customer",cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
    private Payment payment;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<History> history;

}
```

History

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor

@Entity
@Table(name = "history")
public class History {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "history_id")
    private Long historyId;

    @Column(name = "amount_paid")
    private Long AmountPaid;

    

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "payment_date")
    private String paymentDate;

   
    @Column(name = "due")
    private Long due;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(optional = false,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_f_id",referencedColumnName = "customer_id")
    private Customer customer;
```

payment

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "payment")
public class Payment {
    public Long normalPrice =220L;
    public Long sportsPrice = 250L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "payment_id")
    private Long paymentId;

    @Nonnull
    @Column(name = "amount_paid")
    private Long paid;

    @Nullable
    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "payment_date")
    private String paymentDate;

    @Nullable
    @Column(name = "due")
    private Long due;


    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_f_id",referencedColumnName = "customer_id")
    private Customer customer;
```

stb

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "stbox")
public class Stb {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "stb_id")
    private Long StbId;

    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "stbox_number")
    private String StboxNumber;

    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "stbox_id")
    private String StboxId;

    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "stbox_cust_number")
    private String StboxCustNumber;
    
    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "stbox_type")
    private String StboxType;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne(optional = false,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_f_id",referencedColumnName = "customer_id")
    private Customer customer;
```

im new to springboot , i just assigned foreign key in many ways i watched many tutorials and blogs and tried it out but it all failed , the foreign key is always set to null, anybody help , thanks in advance :) .

im trying to create a foreign key in stb , payment ,history but i refered it correctly but it ssets to null

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting both sides of the joins?

```
public class Customer {
  public void setStb(Stb stb) {
    this.stb = stb;
    stb.customer = this;
  }
}
```

or outside maybe?

```
public void setCustomerStb(Customer customer, Stb stb) {
  customer.setStb(stb);
  stb.setCustomer(customer);
}
```

The same also applies to the other joins.